# R calculate percentage without turning the data frame into a wide data frame and back to long one

Tags: r, pivot, percentage

I'm hoping to calculate a percentage of the the number of new customers over the total number of customers for each tier_1 group. I'm able to do this but only by morphing into a wide data frame which I don't prefer. Is there a way to do this without morphing into a wide data frame?

Here is the copy and pasted version of my first data frame. It's in a long format. The tier_1 category lists each channel twice, one with a new_to_file_string == "New Customer" and once with new_to_file_string == "Returning Customer".

```
new_to_file_string    tier_1               sum
New Customer          Paid Display         1.053554     
New Customer          Paid Search          17429.703628     
New Customer          Paid Shopping        192.840719       
New Customer          Paid Social          5589.378029      
New Customer          Paid Video           301.723091       
New Customer          Podcasts             22.268319        
New Customer          Referring Domain     655.758022       
New Customer          Unmapped Events      105.928832       
Returning Customer    Affiliate            410.585386       
Returning Customer    Audio                32.556144
```

And here is the dput version:

```
structure(list(new_to_file_string = c("New Customer", "New Customer", 
"New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", 
"New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", 
"New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", 
"New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", "New Customer", 
"Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", 
"Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", 
"Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", 
"Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", 
"Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", "Returning Customer", 
"Returning Customer"), tier_1 = c("Affiliate", "Audio", "Customer Referral", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Organic Social", 
"Organic Video", "OTT", "Paid Display", "Paid Search", "Paid Shopping", 
"Paid Social", "Paid Video", "Podcasts", "Referring Domain", 
"Unmapped Events", "Affiliate", "Audio", "Direct", "Display", 
"Email", "Organic Search", "Organic Social", "Organic Video", 
"OTT", "Paid Search", "Paid Shopping", "Paid Social", "Paid Video", 
"Podcasts", "Referring Domain", "Unmapped Events"), sum = c(971.6513387549, 
20.9797788595, 4.0590886922, 3506, 80.2643802952, 1420.5576826329, 
1556.3489737375, 349.5952195416, 367.403281163, 1364.4860623594, 
1.0535537876, 17429.7036282718, 192.8407187215, 5589.378028519, 
301.7230914497, 22.2683186546, 655.7580222743, 105.9288322873, 
410.5853859286, 32.5561439337, 7327, 176.1993862616, 2222.2366388167, 
899.3438590657, 58.5263954508, 47.8624061728, 463.8330675232, 
4519.7009051073, 25.9581954589, 963.1761381512, 34.2195099128, 
12.7666333106, 276.6026075478, 37.4327273523)), row.names = c(NA, 
-34L), groups = structure(list(new_to_file_string = c("New Customer", 
"Returning Customer"), .rows = structure(list(1:18, 19:34), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my attempt: I created a pivot_wider version, changed the column names and created a new variable using the mutate function:

```
new_vs_returning2 <- pivot_wider(new_vs_returning, names_from = new_to_file_string, values_from = sum)

colnames(new_vs_returning2) <- c("Channel", "Returning_Customers", "New_Customers")

new_vs_returning2 <- new_vs_returning2 %>%
  mutate(Percent_New_Customers = New_Customers / (Returning_Customers + New_Customers)) %>%
  mutate(Percent_Returning_Customers = (1 - Percent_New_Customers))
```

Here is the c+p version of the new data frame:

```
Channel             Returning_Customers  New_Customers  Percent_New_Customers
Affiliate           971.651339       410.58539     0.2970442    
Audio               20.979779        32.55614      0.6081177    
Customer Referral   4.059089         NA            NA   
Direct              3506.000000      7327.00000    0.6763593    
Display             80.264380        176.19939     0.6870342    
Email               1420.557683      2222.23664    0.6100363    
Organic Search      1556.348974      899.34386     0.3662282    
Organic Social      349.595220       58.52640      0.1434043    
Organic Video       367.403281       47.86241      0.1152573    
OTT                 1364.486062      463.83307     0.2536937
```

And here is the dput version of the new data frame:

```
structure(list(Channel = c("Affiliate", "Audio", "Customer Referral", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Organic Social", 
"Organic Video", "OTT", "Paid Display", "Paid Search", "Paid Shopping", 
"Paid Social", "Paid Video", "Podcasts", "Referring Domain", 
"Unmapped Events"), Returning_Customers = c(971.6513387549, 20.9797788595, 
4.0590886922, 3506, 80.2643802952, 1420.5576826329, 1556.3489737375, 
349.5952195416, 367.403281163, 1364.4860623594, 1.0535537876, 
17429.7036282718, 192.8407187215, 5589.378028519, 301.7230914497, 
22.2683186546, 655.7580222743, 105.9288322873), New_Customers = c(410.5853859286, 
32.5561439337, NA, 7327, 176.1993862616, 2222.2366388167, 899.3438590657, 
58.5263954508, 47.8624061728, 463.8330675232, NA, 4519.7009051073, 
25.9581954589, 963.1761381512, 34.2195099128, 12.7666333106, 
276.6026075478, 37.4327273523), Percent_New_Customers = c(0.297044188304731, 
0.60811773170435, NA, 0.676359272593003, 0.687034229541257, 0.610036264120559, 
0.366228156491009, 0.143404302298201, 0.115257310277352, 0.253693712406205, 
NA, 0.205914511176559, 0.118639507678258, 0.146992472500331, 
0.101861180374308, 0.364397054783492, 0.296669119974079, 0.261107143689027
)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I feel like I'm able to compute the percentage correctly but I now have a wide data frame instead of a long one. I'm able to get back to a long data frame with this method:

```
new_vs_returning2 <- new_vs_returning2 %>%
  dplyr::select(Channel, Percent_New_Customers, Percent_Returning_Customers)

new_vs_returning2 <- pivot_longer(new_vs_returning2, names_to = "Customer Type", values_to = "Percentage", 2:3)
```

But is there a more efficient method / another way to calculate the percentage of new customers over the total customers (new + returning) (and also percentage of returning customers over total customers) without morphing the data frame into a wide data frame and back into a long one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution (wide form) values for Returning Customer and New Customer are swapped, so % is calculated incorrectly.

I suggest this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(tier_1) %>%
    summarize(perc_new = sum[which(new_to_file_string == 'New Customer')]/ sum(sum))
```

Resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 2
   tier_1            perc_new
   <chr>             <dbl>
 1 Affiliate         0.703
 2 Audio             0.392
 3 Customer Referral 1    
 4 Direct            0.324
 5 Display           0.313
 6 Email             0.390
 7 Organic Search    0.634
 8 Organic Social    0.857
 9 Organic Video     0.885
10 OTT               0.746
11 Paid Display      1    
12 Paid Search       0.794
13 Paid Shopping     0.881
14 Paid Social       0.853
15 Paid Video        0.898
16 Podcasts          0.636
17 Referring Domain  0.703
18 Unmapped Events   0.739
```

Comment: first off, good catch on the incorrect label which made the percentage swapped

this is really good solution thanks for sharing. I see that the group_by captured the one level and the summarize(x = sum[which  captured the other level